# To list all files in Amazon s3 bucket using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I need to list all files in Amazon S3 bucket. So I wrote the following code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_KEY = 'MY_KEY'
AWS_SECRET = 'MY_SECRET'
aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('bucketname')

for file_key in bucket.list():
    print file_key.name
```

But whenever I run this code, the following error comes:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto.s3'; 'boto' is not a
>   package [Finished in 0.1s]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do following steps:

1. start the virtualenv
2. `pip install boto`

and then try to run your program

Comment: might be you are running program directly in shell, @Ashima.  If you are running by using `virtualenv` the you have to install `boto` library